# Forms authentication stopped working

Tags: asp.net, form-authentication

I have been using following (Asp.net Forms authentication)code some years ago on a former project to authorize users. But why is it no longer working?

**This code from the web.config in the "safe" folder:**

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
            <authorization>                     
            <allow roles="User" /> 
            <deny users="*"/>       
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**This is the code in the login.aspx:**

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, TextBox1.Text, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(6000), false, "User");
string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
Response.Redirect("LoggedOn/SafePage.aspx");
```

Comment: And I also noticed that Chrome says that the cookie will runout when browsersession ends!

Comment: When mentioning that it does not work, it may be good to add in which way it's failing along with any error messages and similar info.

Comment: I get this message: Error Message: HTTP 401.2 - Unauthorized: Logon Failed Due to Server Configuration with No Authentication

Comment: And I am right now working on "localhost"

Comment: what is means not working, and what is the web.config setup ?

Comment: @user3160735 The error message basically means that someone turned off the authentication method you're using in IIS on the server. [Enabling it](https://technet.microsoft.com/sv-se/library/cc771077(v=ws.10).aspx) will most likely solve your problem.